# stop asking I trust this computer

Tags: windows, usb, app-store-connect

My OS version 12.5.6, and my windows 10

Can I really trust my computer so I do not get the message each time I plug it ??

Answer (score -1):

The 'interesting' things are still not accessible ;)
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202778

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I’m interested in know how to use your answer. Why is interesting single quoted? Is your point that the OP may be changing the trusted computer? I’m not, yet still need to trust each time.

Comment: The original question was far too vague, “for what specific reason, do you not ‘trust’ your computer?”  Trust is allowing access to one device, from another.  Therefore, one has concerns on, what? The really interesting parts of the system are not accessible. The question itself should be down voted…